# For CRaSH shell why do we need fully qualified name and if error messages can be displayed

Tags: corda

With regards to CRaSH shell, we noticed that we need fully qualified names in certain running of functions e.e.g running the flow in startflowdynamics where the call function has to be net.core.newFlow. While i can appreciate that there could be same flow class names e.g. net.core1.newFlow or net.core2.newFlow, but other flows name like newFlow vs newNewFlow are very distinct.

Q1: why do we need to put fully qaulified names even when the class names are so distinct.

Q2: Can we modified the CRaSH shell to resolve the class names with fully qualifed names as it is quite annoying for CLS to input long lines.

Q3: The CRaSH shell doesn't display error messages which I would need to view the log instead. Are there ways I could get the CLS to display error messages when the flow has exception error or as a matter of fact any exception thrown?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1 and Q2:** You don't need to use the fully-qualified class name when starting a flow, unless the unqualified class name is ambiguous. For example, when running the Example CorDapp, I can start a flow from the CRaSH shell by running:

```
flow start Initiator
```

**Q3:** Like every other application interacting with the node, the CRaSH shell communicates with the node via RPC. Any internal errors are not sent over RPC for security reasons.